# Do Google's crawlers interpret Javascript? What if I load a page through AJAX?

Tags: web-crawler

When a user enters my page, I have to make another AJAX call...to load data inside a div.
That's just how my application works.

The problem is...when I view the source of this code, it does not contain the source of that AJAX.  Of course, when I do wget URL ...it also does not show the AJAX HTML. Makes sense.

But what about Google? Will Google be able to crawl the content, as if it's a browser?  How do I allow Google to crawl my page just like a user would see it?

Comment: This question would be better suited on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/; This also not a JS or AJAX question; BTW, the answer could be found by using a search engine, for example Google: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated:** From the answer to [this question about "Ajax generated content, crawling and black listing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003952/ajax-generated-content-crawling-and-black-listing) I found this document about [the way Google crawls AJAX requests](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification) which is part of a collection of documents about [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/).

In short, it means you need to use `<a href="#!data">...</a>` rather than `<a href="#data">...</a>` and then supply a real server-side answer to the URL `path/to/path?_escaped_fragment_=data`.

Also consider a [`<link/>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-link-element.html#the-link-element) tag to supply crawlers with a hint to SEO-friendly content. [`<link rel="canonical"/>`](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/faq#linkrelcanonical), which [this article](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/canonical-url-tag-the-most-important-advancement-in-seo-practices-since-sitemaps) explains a bit, is a good candidate

Note: I took the answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006825/search-engine-misunderstanting/10006925#comment12792862_10006925  because it seems I can't delete mine here.

Comment: As mentioned in the following question, google does now support JavaScript and this answer is outdated. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006825/search-engine-misunderstanting/10006925#comment12792862_10006925

Comment: Answer out of date, is interpreted now..

Comment: Official post: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html

Answer (score 17):

Despite the answers above, apparently it **does** interpret JavaScript, to an extent, [according to Matt Cutts](http://www.searchnewz.com/topstory/news/sn-2-20100315SEOInterviewwithMattCutts.html):

> "For a while, we were scanning within JavaScript, and we were looking for links. Google has gotten smarter about JavaScript and can execute some JavaScript. I wouldn't say that we execute all JavaScript, so there are some conditions in which we don't execute JavaScript. Certainly there are some common, well-known JavaScript things like Google Analytics, which you wouldn't even want to execute because you wouldn't want to try to generate phantom visits from Googlebot into your Google Analytics".

(Why answer an answered question? Mostly because I just saw it because of a duplicate question posted today, and didn't see this info here.)

Answer (score 11):

Actually... Google does have a solution for crawling Ajax applications...

http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 2):

What I do in this situation is always initially populate the page with content based upon the default parameters of whatever the Ajax call is doing. Then I only use the ajax javascript to do updates to the page.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers say, Google's crawler (and I believe those of other search engines) does *not* interpret Javascript -- and you should *not* try to differentiate by user-agent or the like (at the risk of having your site downgraded or blocked for presenting different contents to users vs robots).  Rather, *do* offer some (perhaps minimal) level of content to visitors that have Javascript blocked for whatever reason (including the cases where the reason is "being robots";-) -- after all, that's the very reason the [noscript](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_noscript.asp) tag exists... to make it very, *very* easy to offer such "minimal level of content" (or, more than minimal, if you so choose;-) to non-users of Javascript!

Answer (score 0):

Web crawlers have a difficult time with ajax and javascript that dynamically loads content.  This site has some ideas that show you how to help google index your site http://www.softwaredeveloper.com/features/google-ajax-play-nice-061907/

Answer (score 0):

If you make your pages such that they will work with OR without javascript (i.e. fall back to using frames or standard GET / POST requests to the server if javascript fails, either automatically, or via a "display as plain html" link ), it will be much easier for search engines to crawl the page.

It makes sense for them *not* to crawl "dynamic" content - because it is just that...dynamic.

My understanding is that in most situations, Google does not crawl the client-side-dynamic-content.

Answer (score 0):

Now It looks ike Google bot is not limited to simple `lynx` like browser.

Google bot tries to grab the `Humanly visible` and `Humanly contrasting` text to give importance in different sectors of page. So it renders the page with a `Layout Engine` just like another browser like FF or Chrome have.

It might even have `v8` Javascript Engine support. and the bot might load the page and wait till dom is `ready` and may even wait for few seconds for the page to come to a stable view. and then crop the contrasting text.