# can a meta genenated by js be indexed by google crawled

Tags: meta-tags, google-crawlers

the question is like the title.If I use js to  genenate a meta tag ,and append it to the head tag.can the meta content be indexed by google?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Does Google's crawlers have Javascript? What if I load a page through AJAX?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2061844/425313)

Comment: Short answer: Don't generate meta tags with JS.

Answer (score 0):

it should not in my understanding.

Unless it has recently changes, javascript are not executed by crawlers.
It seems that googlebot has a basic support but you should not rely on it.